# Get the exact contents of a textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have a text area that looks like this:

```
<textarea id="txtBody" name="txtBody">q2312312312<strong>313213213</strong>21231321231231 &lt; &amp;lt;</textarea>
```

When I do this in javascript:

```
var t = document.getElementById('txtBody').value;
```

I get this back:

```
<p>q2312312312<strong>313213213</strong>21231321231231 < &lt;</p>
```

Seems like it should just give me the exact characters as they are... am I missing something? Is there a way to get the exact characters out of a text area?

Comment: What's interesting is that getting innerHTML returns: `q2312312312&lt;strong&gt;313213213&lt;/strong&gt;21231321231231&amp; &lt; &amp;lt;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> am I missing something?

`&` is HTML for "Start an entity".

When you put the text into the HTML document (between the start and end tags for the textarea), you are failing to represent that text as HTML.

As a result, the browser performs error recovery and treats `<strong>` as "A less than character, the word strong, then a greater than character" (because tags are not allowed inside a `textarea` element, but treats `&lt;` as "A less than character" because there isn't a machine detectable error here.

> Is there a way to get the exact characters out of a text area?

You need to write the HTML correctly in the first place.

```
<textarea id="txtBody" name="txtBody">q2312312312&lt;strong&gt;313213213&lt;/strong&gt;21231321231231 &amp;lt; &amp;amp;lt;</textarea>
```

Comment: @JJC - also note that sending the textarea content to the browser in the page source as you are showing is different than typing that text into an originally empty textarea.  When you send the text the browser gets to interpret it before setting the content/value of the textarea.

Comment: The problem and the solution are still the same. You need to express characters that have special meaning in HTML as entities, otherwise they take on their special meaning (or trigger error recovery algorithms).

Comment: That did it, html encoding before stuffing it in the <textarea> has fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI, my new textarea looks like this:<textarea id="txtBody" name="txtBody" >q2312312312&lt;strong&gt;313213213&lt;/strong&gt;21231321231231 &amp;lt; &amp;amp;lt;</textarea>

Answer (score 1):

I get the right contents, I guess your (X)HTML is not valid...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>untitled</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 0.19.1" />
</head>

<body>
    <textarea id="txtBody" name="txtBody">q2312312312<strong>313213213</strong>21231321231231& &lt; &amp;lt;</textarea>
    <script>
        var t = document.getElementById('txtBody').value;
        alert(t);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, you are right my innerhtml was not valid. It's fixed now, yippee!